# Easiest way to persist/cache a web response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm playing with node.js. Using [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), I want to create a simple web proxy that makes the request and then stash the response somewhere before passing back the response. If I then detect no internet connection or some flag is set somewhere, I want to replay the response that I have stashed away. So the URL would be the "key" and the entire response would be the "value".

My question is, what's the easiest way to serialize this response object so that it can be replayed later? I was looking at mongodb and mongoosejs, but I'm put off because mongoose wants me to create a schema for my object, and I just want to dump the entire response object somewhere (with the URL as a key). Is there an easier way?

Here's my super simple node.js proxy code:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var server = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {

  var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(req);

  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'url.to.proxy.com',
    port: 80,
    buffer: buffer
  });
});

server.proxy.on('end', function (req) {
  console.log("The request was proxied.",req.url);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: MongoDB wants you to create a schema? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Mongoose does - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: Then don't use Mongoose, just stick with mongodb.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Many ORMs and ODMs endorse a pre-defined yet flexible schema for MongoDB, in fact many have gone as far as to say that MongoDB is not schemaless but schema-flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to store the response object in a file; you don't need a database.

1. Create a response object cache directory.
2. Hash the URL using SHA-256 and use the result as your file name.
3. Stream the response object to/from the file.

Comment: Nice, much simpler than messing with mongodb, 'cos as you said I can just stream to it.